# Lateral Menu app doesn't run

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to build an ActionBar menu app but when I lanuch it in the simulator the following message is showed:

Unfortunately, Mapa has stopped.

Here is the code:

Main Activity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Mapapp extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapapp);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuopc, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

menuopc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mapa"
        android:title="@string/t1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always|ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:title="@string/t2"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="always|ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

activity_mapapp.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Mapapp" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: On what Android version are you running this? What does the LogCat print?

Comment: I am running in Android 4 version.

Comment: I saw the LogCat and I fixed the issue. The problem was in this message: 02-27 20:09:31.981: E/AndroidRuntime(798): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS, SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM, and SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER are mutually exclusive.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Change your menu options to either android:showAsAction="ifRoom" or android:showAsAction="always"  .. You can't use both

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ifRoom and always in the same item. Device doesn't know how to behave if there is not enough space in Action Bar to display action item.

*ifRoom* - Only place this item in the Action Bar if there is room for it.

*always* - Always place this item in the Action Bar. Avoid using this unless it's critical that the item always appear in the action bar. Setting multiple items to always appear as action items can result in them overlapping with other UI in the action bar.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html